# Processing 3 - Filling a shape after using noFill()

Tags: java, processing

I'm currently trying to create a form of drawing application and I have just implemented a poly-line feature using createShape().

The problem is, when drawing the shape, the user would most likely not want it to be filled, so I have used noFill(). After drawing, however, when endShape is called I would like to fill the shape (assuming correct circumstances are met), and just using PShape.setFill(colour) does not work unfortunately.

E.g.

```
Pshape s;
s = createShape();
s.beginShape();
s.noFill();

drawShape(s);

s.endShape();
if(fill.selected) s.setFill(colour);
```

Is there any way of doing this, or will I just have to not use noFill ?
Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Can you keep track of the points the user clicks in an ArrayList and then draw the shape using fill after they're done drawing them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use [fill()](http://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PShape.html#fill-int-) as long as you use it within `beginShape()`/`endShape()` calls.

Here's a rough example:

```
PShape s;

boolean useFill;

void setup(){

  size(300,300);
  s = createShape();
  s.beginShape();
  s.noFill();
  s.vertex(30,30);
  s.vertex(120,30);
  s.vertex(30,120);
  s.vertex(30,30);// close shape, repeat last vertex
  s.endShape();

}

void draw(){
  background(127 + (frameCount % 127));
  shape(s);
  text("press any key to toggle fill",10,15);
}

void keyPressed(){
  useFill = !useFill;

  if(useFill){
    s.beginShape();
    s.fill(color(192,0,0));
    s.endShape();
  }else{
    s.beginShape();
    s.noFill();
    s.endShape();
  }
}
```